# Rule `transform: translateY` in menu doesn’t work properly when menu is loaded in multiple pages through JS

Tags: javascript, html, menu, include

A menu included in multiple pages with a small JS (following advice from this Stackoverflow post: [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)) has the following rule: `.header_area.navbar_fixed .main_menu {transform: translateY(70px);}`. It works perfectly when the menu is put direcly on the page (not through JS). But when loaded through JS, the `transform: translate` rule of the menu doesn’t work. Here is the demo: https://guardian-angels.glitch.me/. And this is how the menu behaves when menu is directly on the page (not through JS): https://guardian-angels.glitch.me/en/projects-for-future-humanity.html. Can anybody help me please?

I have tried changing the following rule: `.header_area {position:absolute;}` to `position: fixed`; but it didn’t do the trick. I have searched in Google but haven’t found anything that can help me. I also tried changing `.header_area.navbar_fixed .main_menu {position: fixed;}` to `position: absolute` (following some advice I found in Google) and it didn't do the trick either.

This is the html for the menu:

```
    <header class="header_area">
        <div class="main_menu">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                    <div class="container">


                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse offset" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu_nav ml-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mn_home" href="">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mn_projects" href="">Projects</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mn_about" href="">About</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mn_communiques" href="">Communiqu&eacute;s</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mn_donate" href="">Donate</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                                    <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Languages</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="nav-item  mn_english"><a class="nav-link" href="">English</a></li>
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Spanish</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mn_contact" href="">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Menu is loaded through an include with small JS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Some Title Here</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
  $(function(){
    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
      var file = '/en/inc/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';
      $(this).load(file);
    });
  });
        </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-include="menu"></div><!-- Include code to load navigation menu - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the css that doesn't work when menu is loaded through small JS (the `transform: translate` rule:

```
.header_area.navbar_fixed .main_menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: -70px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #222222;
    transform: translateY(70px);
    transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
    }
```

The expected behavior is that the menu should go up with the page (as shown in: https://guardian-angels.glitch.me/en/projects-for-future-humanity.html) and then come back as `position: fixed`; to the top of the page, but it just goes up and doesn't come back.

Comment: I'd the same problem, I refactor my code to get it working.
I didn't find another way to solve this.

Comment: Somebody gave me this solution (https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-hide-reveal-a-sticky-header-on-scroll-with-javascript--cms-33756), which I'm trying to implement

Comment: @LeoGasparrini, your solution might seem to be the only one I have as of now, but I'd really wouln't know how to do that. Any suggestions, please?